# Unable to add Window error

Tags: android, exception, dialog

i am using tabWidget. i have a date picker in my child class  when i go first time from parent class to child class and select date it works fine and when i go again from parent class to child class and select date  the app crashes  with logcat result "Unable to add window"

it works fine for the first time but not for the next time 
code is following

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class PlaceOrder extends Activity {
    public TextView tvDisplayDate,personName,Cname,cAdrress;
    public DatePicker dpResult;
    public Button btnChangeDate;
    Button cancel,submit;
    public int year;
    public int month;
    public int day;
    int requestCode;
    int resultCode;
    Intent data;
    String Name,cName,Title,Address,Phone,Email;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.placeorder);
        personName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        Cname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Cname);
        cAdrress=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.CAddname);
        personName.setText(AccountInfo.fnameNlName);
        Cname.setText(AccountInfo.cName);
        cAdrress.setText(AccountInfo.cAdd);
        setCurrentDateOnView();
        addListenerOnButton();
        final PlaceOrder PO = this;
        cancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Cancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(FastPkgMainActivity.fastPackge==1)
                {
                    Intent fastPkgQuote = new Intent(v.getContext(), FastPkgQuote.class);
                    StringBuffer urlString = new StringBuffer();
                    FastPkgQuote parentActivity = (FastPkgQuote)getParent();
                    parentActivity.replaceContentView("fastpkg1", fastPkgQuote);
                }
                else if(FastPkgMainActivity.fastPackge==2)
                {
                    Intent fastpkgQuoteNew = new Intent(v.getContext(), FastPkgQuoteNew.class);
                    StringBuffer urlString = new StringBuffer();
                    FastPkgQuoteNew parentActivity = (FastPkgQuoteNew)getParent();
                    parentActivity.replaceContentView1("fastPkg2", fastpkgQuoteNew);
                }
                // TO*DO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        }
        );
        submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Submit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Name=AccountInfo.fnameNlName.toString();
                    cName=AccountInfo.cName.toString();
                    Title=AccountInfo.title.toString();
                    Address=AccountInfo.cAdd.toString();
                    Phone=AccountInfo.phno.toString();
                    Email=AccountInfo.E_ID.toString();
                }
                catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    Name=" ";
                    cName=" ";
                    Title=" ";
                    Address=" ";
                    Phone=" ";
                    Email=" ";
                }
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                //String[] recipients = new String[]{
                    "mymail@email.com", "sales@fastpkg.com",
                }
                ;
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[] {
                    "sales@fastpkg.com"
                }
                );
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Placing an Order");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "CustomerDetails       " +
                " Name"+":  "+Name+
                "CompanyName:"+"  "+cName+
                "Title :"+Title+
                "Address: "+Address+
                "Phone #: "+Phone+
                "Email :"+Email
                );
                emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail client :"),RESULT_OK);
                onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }
        );
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
    Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                if(FastPkgMainActivity.fastPackge==1)
                {
                    Intent fastpkgQuote = new Intent();
                    StringBuffer urlString = new StringBuffer();
                    fastpkgQuote.setClass(getParent(), FastPkgQuote.class);
                    FastPkgQuote parentActivity = (FastPkgQuote)getParent();
                    parentActivity.replaceContentView("fastPkg2", fastpkgQuote);
                }
                else if(FastPkgMainActivity.fastPackge==2)
                {
                    Intent fastpkgQuoteNew = new Intent();
                    StringBuffer urlString = new StringBuffer();
                    fastpkgQuoteNew.setClass(getParent(),
                    FastPkgQuoteNew.class);
                    FastPkgQuoteNew parentActivity =
                    (FastPkgQuoteNew)getParent();
                    parentActivity.replaceContentView1("fastPkg2",
                    fastpkgQuoteNew);
                }
            }
            else if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
            {
                final PlaceOrder pOrder = this;
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(pOrder, ThnkYouPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
    // display current date
    public void setCurrentDateOnView() {
        tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        dpResult = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpResult);
        dpResult.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        // set current date into textview
        tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
        // Month is 0 based, just add 1
        .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
        .append(year).append(" "));
        // set current date into datepicker
        dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);
    }
    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        btnChangeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeDate);
        btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        }
        );
    }
    @Override
    public  Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            // set date picker as current date
            return new DatePickerDialog(this.getParent(), datePickerListener, year, month,
            day);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public  DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
        int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDay;
            // set selected date into textview
            tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
            .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
            .append(" "));
            // set selected date into datepicker also
            dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);
        }
    }
    ;
}
```

Comment: Its looking ungly. First, Format the code by yourself so its easily readable to others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `OnCreateDialog` method, in the line:

```
return new DatePickerDialog(this.getParent(), datePickerListener, year, month,day);
```

use `application basecontext` instead of `this.getparent()`

it might help you.

Comment: can you please more elaborate with a dummy example ?

Comment: should i use getbaseContext() then getParent ()  or should i use getApplicationContext then getParent() ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this:

```
return new DatePickerDialog(this.getParent(), datePickerListener, year, month,
            day);
```

Try this and see if it works:

```
return new DatePickerDialog(PlaceOrder.this, datePickerListener, year, month,
                day);
```